# On independence and normal random variables

Tags: statistics, normal-distribution, expected-value, independence, covariance

**Question**

Let $Z_1, \ldots, Z_n$ be independent and identically distributed standard normal random variables. What are the constants $c_1, \ldots, c_n$ (not all zero) such that the random variable $$M = c_1Z_1 + \ldots + c_nZ_n$$ is independent of $Z_i - M$ for each $i = 1, \ldots, n$?

**My working**

$\because Z_i \stackrel{\mathrm{iid}}{\sim} \mathcal{N} (0, 1)$

$\therefore M \sim \mathcal{N} (0, c_1^2 + \ldots + c_n^2)$

$\begin{aligned}[t]
Cov(Z_i - M,\ M) & = Cov(Z_i,\ M) - Var(M)
\\[1 mm] & = \mathbb{E}(Z_iM) - \mathbb{E}(Z_i)\mathbb{E}(M) - Var(M)
\\[1 mm] & = \mathbb{E}(Z_iM) - (c_1^2 + \ldots + c_n^2)
\\[1 mm] & = 0
\end{aligned}$

$\implies \mathbb{E}(Z_iM) = c_1^2 + \ldots + c_n^2$

However, this is where I am stuck. How do I find the expectation of $Z_iM$? Any intuitive suggestions will be greatly appreciated :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$Z_1-M,Z_2-M,...,Z_n-M,M$ are jointly normal with mean $0$. So indepedence of $M$ and $Z_i-M$ is equiavlent to $E(Z_i-M)M=0$. But $EZ_iM=\sum c_jEZ_iZ_j=\sum c_jEZ_iEZ_j=c_i$ since $EZ_iZ_j=1$ for $i=j$ and $0$ for $i \neq j$. So the conidtion is $c_i=EM^{2}=\sum c_k^{2}$ for each $i$.  Thus $c_i$ is a number $c$ independent of $i$ and $c=nc^{2}$ so, $c=0$ or $c=\frac 1 n$. $c=0$ has been ruled out so $c_i=\frac 1  n$ for all $n$.

Comment: Thank you for you answer! I am just having difficulty at the part where you expand $\mathbb{E}(Z_iM)$. In particular, how did you get $\mathbb{E}(Z_iM) = \sum [c_j\mathbb{E}(Z_iZ_j)]$?

Comment: @EthanMark Expectation is linear.

Comment: Sorry, just one more thing. So essentially we are trying to solve $c_1 + \ldots + c_n = c_1^2 + \ldots + c_n^2$ right? But why do you use $i$ for the LHS and $k$ for the RHS of your condition? I am a little lost there as well and am also having trouble understanding how you conclude that all the $c$s must be the same number.

Comment: We want $M$  to be independent of $Z_i-M$ for each $i$.So the condition is $c_i=c_1^{2}+c_2^{2}+...+c_n^{2}$ for every $i$. There is no sum over $i$ on the left side. [$EZ_iM=\sum_k EZ_ic_kZ_K=c_i$ since all terms vanish except the one where $k=i$]. @EthanMark

Comment: Oh yes, I see, but the question states that the $c$s cannot be all $0$, so am I correct to say that the only solution is $c = \frac 1 n$?

Comment: @EthanMark Yes, I have edited my answer.